# Witnesses of Kiddushin no need to know the couple?

Tags: halacha-theory, marriage, edim-witnesses

The Jewish Halacha does not require the witnesses to familiarize themselves with the couple prior to Kiddushin:

- they are not required to know the couple in person before the wedding or have any relations with them
- they are not required to know their names or check their IDs (keep in mind that the Ketubah (bearing the names) is NOT required for the wedding)
- same for personal or family background (whether they are Arayos to each other, for example, or if they are Jewish at all)
- neither they are required to [be able to] distinguish them from their twin siblings
- they are not required to even see their faces, they can see them both from behind, they only need to see the transfer and hear the words!

All those conditions render the witnessing pretty much useless, as you don't even know who you witnessed, so you can never be called to testify.

If I'm wrong - please prove me wrong, if not - **what's the logic of having such witnesses that have no idea who's getting married**, what did the Torah want not specifying additional obligating conditions for witnesses?

Comment: They clearly have some idea. Any line you draw will be arbitrary.

Comment: @DoubleAA Please remind me the meaning of -1 for a question?

Comment: They can recognize their faces and so would subsequently be able to testify as to the married status of the individuals involved.

Comment: @JoelK I bet if you witness a wedding at Gur for example you have about 50% chance to recognize the guy a week or a month later. What's it worth?

Comment: @JoelK How they are to be called to testify if they don't know names?  How do you look for Eidim for a couple if the Eidim don't know names?

Comment: Something approximating "not valuable". This post is just a list of things witnesses wouldn't need to know to testify about what they saw happened , a false claim about what they do know , and a complaint that our standards for weddings are the same as for capital crimes. Kind of a waste of space if you ask me. Maybe if you didn't exaggerate and presented the situation accurately you could find something interesting to ask.

Comment: I thought that the witnesses serve to witness an act between two people, whoever those people happen to be. If I see two people (any two) and one gives another something of value and says words, I have "witnessed" the marriage even if I don't know the people involved (at least that's how I understood the eidut here).

Comment: @AlBerko JoelK Witnesses testify without knowing names in all sorts of contexts, Jewish and secular. (Ever seen a victim pick a suspect out of a line up?) This is obviously not a problem to anyone else

Comment: @rosends You are right, that's what it is acc. to the Halachah. but this all renders the witnessing useless.

Comment: @rosends AlBerko This gets in to the classical *lomdishe* question of how to define *eidei kiyyum* and what their purpose is

Comment: @JoelK rosends double I added that seeing faces is not required either (At least I understood so). So what's left?

Comment: @AlBerko That is by no means obvious https://www.sefaria.org/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.31.5?lang=he

Comment: @JoelK That's interesting, but it also says that the failing was "lo ra'u han'tinah" so their witnessing also is based on watching an act.

Comment: @Rosends He is comparing and contrasting the case where they don't see the woman's face, to a different case where they heard the man announce his intention to perform kiddushin, but didn't see the transfer of the object (in that case an etrog).

Answer (score 2):

Even granting all your assumptions that the witnesses may have no way of identifying the woman at all, [Pitchei Teshuvah to Even HaEzer 31:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Pithei_Teshuva_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Even_HaEzer.31.5?lang=he) points out that they would be able to testify as to her status as a married woman, if another man were to sleep with her in front of them there and then:

> ולענ"ד בפשיטות **דהכא חשיב ידיעה וראיה כיון דמהני עדותן אם יראו שבעל איש אחר את האשה בפניהם** כו' כמו שאם יראו עדים לאחד שהיו פניו מכוסה רצח לחבירו וכי לא היו יכולין להעיד שאיש הלזה הרג לחבירו אף שאם היה מתרחק מהם לא הי' מכירין אותו ולא היו יכולין להעיד מ"מ בודאי מהני עדותן וחשיב שפירש ידיעה וראיה:‏

Comment: Notably, the witnesses could die 2 minutes later with no consequence to the marriage, so it can't be we need effective witnesses beyond that moment.

Comment: 1. I don't see any logic here, he just states מהני עדותן, but not why. How if they did not see her face, neither heard her voice? What does *"ועוד כיון שלא זזו ידם עד שבדקוה וראוה בודאי הרי הוא כידיע'"* means.

Comment: I think, you forgot to add **לע"ד** which means approximately **"it appears to me that"** which is a very important distinction here. That's why I think this downrates the answer, but not you! Your ability to find answers is truly amazing.

Comment: @AlBerko The point is that they don’t need to see her voice or recognize her face. If she commits adultery immediately following the kiddushin, she can be brought straight to beit din, and the witnesses will testify that this woman here (although we don’t know her name or what she looks like) is married.

Comment: @AlBerko ועוד כיון שלא זזו ידם עד שבדקוה וראוה בודאי הרי הוא כידיע is not relevant here (so I have deleted it from the quote). It’s referring to the case under discussion in Pitchei Teshuvah where the witnesses did not see her face during the kiddushin, but did see it immediately afterward.

Comment: @AlBerko I’m not sure I follow your point about ולפע״ד. Care to expand?

Comment: THere's something intrinsically wrong with the way people react to some deep and serious question - instead of grasping the magnitude of a problem they just deny it by trying to find the slightest texts that seemingly disprove the question. And that seems wrong to me. THere's no problem to find a possible disproval almost for anything in Judaism, and still a single opinion does not change anything, moreover, it just strengthens the point - ללמד על הכלל כולו יצא - that nobody else thinks so!

Comment: @AlBerko or maybe the question isn't as deep and serious as you thought. maybe if no one else is grasping the magnitude, there isn't a magnitude to grasp